# Can't install MS Office 2010 under Wine 4.0.3 Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wine

I have been able to successfully install wine-stable on my Ubuntu Mate 19.10 laptop. But trying to install MS Office 2010 causes the Office installer to die with this error:

002b:err:msi:MSI_OpenDatabaseW unknown flag (nil)

Any help greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried a couple of variants. wine-stable seems to install version 4.0.3. I also tried the version 4.0.2 from the ubuntu repositories (without adding the wine repo) and had the same error.